# Remove multiple PDF passwords with workflow or applescript in a folder

Tags: macos, applescript

How do I remove passwords from multiple PDF files using `Applescript` or by creating a `Workflow` in **OS X**?

My scenario is that I have multiple password protected PDF files in a **folder**. I know the passwords for all, which is same. I want to be able to run a Workflow on this folder so that all PDFs inside it are unlocked by the workflow.

OR run an Applescript shell code on all these files at once

I also preferably want to be able to create a way where putting / moving / pasting any PDF in the folder automatically unlocks it :)

Help appreciated !!

---

**Update**:

I have tried [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/). The following code works awesome in **Terminal**, once pdftk is installed

```
pdftk secured.pdf input_pw foopass output unsecured.pdf
```

Now I want to be able to **create a workflow** that runs this command on **selected** files or on all the files in a folder

Comment: tried **pdftk** - http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/

Comment: For anyone else stumbling across this today, try [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net) (available via homebrew: `brew install qpdf`)

Comment: for qpdf the command to use is `qpdf --decrypt --password=PASSWORD --replace-input MY.PDF`

Comment: `qpdf` works, even for pdfs that have security set to disable printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of "Folder Actions"? It's a way to attach an applescript to a folder so that whenever a new file is added to the folder the applescript is run. A quick google search turned up [this](http://www.macworld.com/article/1167157/automate_tasks_with_folder_actions.html) which will give you directions on how to set it up. You can do more google searching if you still have questions.

Here's an applescript you can use with folder actions. I didn't test it but it should work (it's basic code). This will do its stuff on only pdf files. Other files you add to the folder will be left alone. **NOTE**: you have to put in your values for the first 4 variables of the script.

Good luck.

```
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theItems

    -- enter your values here
    set pdftkPosixPath to "/usr/bin/pdftk"
    set pWord to "foopass"
    set appendedName to "_unlocked" -- text to append to the file name
    set shouldTrash to true -- true or false, move the locked file to the trash after unlocking?

    set fContainer to theFolder as text
    repeat with anItem in theItems
        try
            tell application "System Events"
                set fName to name of anItem
                set fExt to name extension of anItem
            end tell

            if fExt is "pdf" and fName does not contain appendedName then
                set baseName to (text 1 thru -5 of fName) & appendedName & ".pdf"
                set newPath to fContainer & baseName
                do shell script (quoted form of pdftkPosixPath & space & quoted form of POSIX path of anItem & " input_pw " & quoted form of pWord & " output " & quoted form of POSIX path of newPath)

                if shouldTrash then
                    tell application "Finder" to move anItem to trash
                end if
            end if
        end try
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

***EDIT***: here's how you can ask for a password. Note that if you want to see the text then remove "with hidden answer".

```
display dialog "Enter a password:" default answer "" with icon note with hidden answer
set theAnswer to text returned of the result
if theAnswer is not "" then set pWord to theAnswer
```

Comment: If I wanted to run it as `on run {input, parameters}`, to be able to right click and choose PDFs to unlock, I loose the folder name (`fContainer`). How do I get that - folder name from a file in applescript?

Comment: Update: got folder name. Now I need the ability to prompt user for Password, and if empty, use the default one.

Comment: I added an edit section to my post to show you how to ask for a password.

Comment: Got it working. Thanks for the same. I assume that I need to put my default password in the `""`, so that even if no Pwd is entered, it uses the default

Comment: You could do that or just use the variable pWord, either works.

Answer (score 2):

The AppleScript command to execute a shell script is do shell script...
So something like this:

```
do shell script "pdftk secured.pdf input_pw foopass output unsecured.pdf"
```

should work. 
At this point I see 2 options:

1. write an AppleScript script that ask the user for the folder or get it from the Finder selection and then execute the command for each file in the folder;
2. write an Automator workflow that get the files from the folder using already available actions and then attach a new action that execute the AppleScript script.

For option 2 you can set an Automator workflow as in the following image.

[image]

Comment: I knew the `do` thing. I wanted to create a workflow that would allow me to run this script on multiple files. The point 2 is what I want help on

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, +1 for the screen and code. But I am accepting the other one, since its mentioning the Folder Actions