# Removing PDF password protection, knowing the password

Tags: objective-c, pdf, encryption

I have a bunch of pdf's I want to remove passwords from. Note that I know the password, so no need for brute forcing. I am working on a mac, so I would like to make an app to remove those passwords.

I have seen apps like wondershare's pdf password remover, so I know it is possible.

Is there a solution/library in the obj-c environment to remove passwords from PDF's?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Comment: Please note that Wondershare products install Chinese-based adware software to your PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I think this would work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352933/remove-multiple-pdf-passwords-with-workflow-or-applescript-in-a-folder). Both answers seem valid, I personally would opt for the second one.

Transcribed:

`do shell script "pdftk secured.pdf input_pw foopass output unsecured.pdf"`

Answer (score 10):

ok. Here is the easy solution.

1. Open the pdf with google chrome.
2. Enter the password.
3. Print document using ctrl+p.
4. Choose Save as pdf option.

Done.

Comment: Confirmed this still works in 2019. Also, you can save it directly to Google Drive from the print menu.

Comment: However, this usually lowers the PDF quality, e.g. the text no longer is selectable, and the vectorized lines become basically an image. So think of this as taking a screenshot of your PDF.

Comment: @Vichoko At least with macOS, the PDF is saved exactly (or at least very similar) to the original including high-res images and selectable text.

Comment: Great to know that @MauriceSchleußinger! Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for PSPDFkit. See this documentation here [Documentation](http://pspdfkit.com/documentation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a way by iterating through all the pdf's and unlocking one by one.I am not sure if you are exactly looking for this type of solution, but may be helpful.

Iterate through all the PDf's and create a CGPDFDocument by passing the exact path of the pdf,
there is a method on CGPDFDocumentRef to check whether the document is password protected, which is "**CGPDFDocumentIsUnlocked**". If it is locked then unlock the file using the method:"**CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword**".

save the unlocked document to a path and from then on you need not unlock each time you access it.

TNQ

Comment: The CGPDFDocument API is read-only, it cannot save the PDF file.

Comment: this seemed to be a very nice solution until I read what @Mihai lancu wrote :(

Comment: @Chrene - Oh! sorry  my pointer is not helpful... TNQ Mihai lancu for the correction  and educating a new thing regarding CGPDFDocumentRef

Answer (score 0):

Using Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro:

1. Open the document by putting the password.
2. Advanced -> Security -> Remove Security
3. Save the document

close and reopen with no password.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i tried:-

1. **Open** the PDF file.
2. **Enter** the password for the **first time**.
3. Now to **remove** password **"ctrl+p"**, then select this ["Microsoft Print To PDF"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROCIO.png.).

4. Then click on **print**,it will ask for **location to save**, give the details where you want to save and save it.
5. Done.

### Note:-

1. To be more precise we don't need any browser for this it can be done in your local system.
2. Sometime you get some bank documents like form-16 etc, it will be password protected and you will not be having permission to modify due to security reason, due to some reason or might be you are using some organization system, so in that case this is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Steps to remove password security:

> 1. Right-click on the PDF file and select “Google Chrome” from the “Open with” menu or drag any password-protected PDF file (bank
>      statement) into your Google Chrome browser.
> 2. Now go to the File menu in Google Chrome and choose Print (or press Ctrl+P on Windows). Choose the destination printer as “Save as PDF”
>      and click the Save button.
> 3. Provide the file name and the file location and your duplicate PDF file will be saved in the specified location. Now upload the saved PDF
>      file.